# Probability - Finding opposite of complement

Tags: probability

If I want to find $P(A \cap B)$, is it $1-P(A^\complement \cap B^\complement)$ or $1-P(A \cap B)^\complement$?

Comment: A *compliment* is a friendly remark. The set of elements not contained in a set is its *complement*.

Comment: So it is! Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: $P(A \cap B)^\complement$ doesn't make sense, $P(A \cap B)$ is a real number from $[0,1]$.

Comment: A Venn diagram will let you quickly identify $A^c\cap B^c$ and $(A\cap B)^c$ visually. Then you can *see* that $1-P((A\cap B)^c)$ is right, and also *see* why the other is in general not right.

Answer (score 2):

The complement of $A\cap B$ is $(A\cap B)^c$, so $P(A\cap B)=1-P\big((A\cap B)^c\big)$. Using one of the de Morgan’s laws you can go further: $(A\cap B)^c=A^c\cup B^c$.